# A Spark job on EMR taking suddenly 30 hours (up from 5 hours)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm relatively new to Spark. I have a Spark job that runs on an Amazon EMR cluster of 1 master and 8 cores. In a nutshell, the Spark job reads some .csv files from S3, transforms them to RDDs, performs some relatively complex joins on the RDDs and finally produces other .csv files on S3.
This job, executed on the EMR cluster, used to take about 5 hours. Suddenly, one of these days, it started to take **over 30 hours** and it does so ever since. There is no apparent difference in the inputs (the S3 files).

I've checked the **logs** and in the lengthy run (30 hours) I can see something about OutOfMemory errors:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.IdentityHashMap.resize(IdentityHashMap.java:472)
        at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:441)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$SearchState.enqueue(SizeEstimator.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$visitSingleObject$1.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$visitSingleObject$1.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitSingleObject(SizeEstimator.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.org$apache$spark$util$SizeEstimator$$estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:69)
....

        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
```

In spite of the apparent OutOfMemory exception(s), the outputs (the S3 files) look good, so apparently the Spark job finishes properly.

What could suddenly produce the jump from 5 hours execution to 30 hours ?
How would you go about investigating such an issue ?

Comment: Without spark logs and historical ui, it would be difficult to debug this. Did you check if there are task/ stage failures and retries?

Comment: It seems something related to a broadcast operation. Can you post your code?

Comment: A couple of things by just looking at your error log. Are you using the broadcast hint in your joins? What is your `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold ` value?

Comment: Indeed, there are task and stage failures. Looking at the logs, I can see many lines like this:
```
[GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-04-18T02:33:56.130+0000: [ParNew: 337920K->18052K(337920K), 0.0216719 secs] 415694K->117109K(1088896K), 0.0217314 secs]
```

Comment: We use some broadcast operations; the stack trace above originates from such a broadcast:

_val myMap = myBase.map(x => (x.uuid, (x.name, x.state, x.type))).collectAsMap_;

_val myMapBroadcast = this.sparkContext.broadcast(myMap)_


Then, this _myMapBroadcast.value_ is passed inside a _.map_ operation.

Comment: I updated this code to use directly myMap (no broadcasts anymore) and after this the job fails with such an error:
```
_org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 259 in stage 51.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 259.3 in stage 51.0 (TID 10155, ip-10-172-18-93.ec2.internal, executor 33): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 33 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 145405 ms_
```
After this, we tried to pass spark.network.timeout=300s, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I can see `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1`

Answer (score 2):

Spark retries on failure. Your processes are failing. When that happens, all active tasks are probably considered failed, so requeued elsewhere in the cluster.

Comment: So that would explain why it takes so long - so many tasks are failing and then queued to be rerun. 
But I still can't explain why this used to work fine, without failures and suddenly it all changed.

Comment: One more thing I noticed: in the short running job there are no killed containers, while in the logs of the long running job I see lots of "Container marked as failed" (and "Container killed on request").

Comment: container failed = the process died. your code is running out of memory, spark then recovers

Comment: Steve, thanks, I've got that part; we'll work on optimising the data structures and the algorithms; on the other hand, I'd like very much to understand what happened - why this suddenly degraded; is there a logical explanation ?

Comment: whatever code you've written causes an OOM on the worker processes -which are executing may tasks in parallel. Whatever change you made (or data change) tipped it over the edge